# Mantener los campos abiertos al editar información

Tags: jquery

Tengo un sistema para registrar pedidos que tiene la siguiente estrutura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

Al hacer clic en el botón **Incluir novo produto**, se abre un produtompo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

Sin embargo, cuando va al área para editar pedidos, los campos permanecen cerrados y no abiertos de acuerdo con las solicitudes registradas. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los campos permanezcan abiertos según las solicitudes registradas en el momento de editar los pedidos?

El código es el siguiente:

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" >
<tr class="linhas">
<td>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold" class="bg-light">Produto</td>
<td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold" class="bg-light">Quantidade</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 40%">
<select name="Produto[]" class="form-control">
  <?php echo $visualizar->visualizarComboProdutos(); ?>
</select>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 30%">
<input type="number" name="Quantidade[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade" min="1" step="1" required>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td style="padding: 5px"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
</tr>              
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="text-right">
<button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-success" title="Adicionar Produto"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Incluir novo produto</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
    $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
      if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      }
    });
  }

  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    //novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
    novoCampo.find('select').val("");
    //novoCampo.find('input[type="radio"]').prop('selected', false);
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: ¿que son campos abiertos o cerrados?  me parece que no hablas español, y posteas preguntas que cuestan de entender, y eso dificulta que te podamos dar respuestas, lo siento.  Quizás te sería más cómodo preguntar en inglés en el sitio de [SO]

Comment: Si te entiendo bien, haces referencia a que el campo esté o no habilitado para su edición. Hay un atributo que es "disable", que permite hacer esto y creo que es lo que busas: `$("tu_elemento").attr( 'disabled', true/false );`